# Implementing biased erasure error in stim

Tags: stim

We are trying to simulate the erasure channel in stim, but it is a biased erasure - meaning that the replaced qubit doesn't have a depolarizing channel but a biased channel.
We saw that there is a function in stim "HERALDED_ERASE" channel, but here the replaced qubit has a depolarizing channel.
Can we use it to have another error channel on the replaced qubit?

Also, when we use MWPM to decode, is the weight of the edge (in the matching graph) associated with the erased qubit updated appropriately?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v1.12, you can use the [`HERALDED_PAULI_CHANNEL_1`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#HERALDED_PAULI_CHANNEL_1) instruction to get biased heralded errors.

Note that you will still need to find a decoder that *understands* the erasures. For example, as of this writing, pymatching will just ignore the heralds and do normal decoding instead of erasure-informed decoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with simulating biased erasure is that resetting the qubit to $|0\rangle$ is not a Pauli channel, while resetting the qubit to the maximally mixed state is. So I'm not sure HERALDED_PAULI_CHANNEL_1 will help... Conditional reset just seems to be a tricky one to simulate efficiently.

(I wanted to comment but I don't have enough reputation haha)

Comment: You can pauli twirl your true erasure noise to get a `HERALDED_PAULI_CHANNEL_1`  that approximates it. The nature of the actual erasure will depend on the hardware; e.g. when a photon is erased it's not in the |0> state it's escaped.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/13707)